# Is UB in unevaluated context (e.g. requires-expressions) still UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, c++-concepts

The C++ 20 [draft](https://wg21.link/n4861) [concept.default.init] does not precisely define `default_initializable`

```
template<class T>
concept default_initializable = constructible_from<T> &&
    requires { T{}; } &&
    is-default-initializable <T>; // exposition-only
```

and describe what *is-default-initializable* should do with the following words:

> For a type `T`, *is-default-initializable* <T> is true if and only if the variable definition
>
> `T t;`
>
> is well-formed for some invented variable t; otherwise it is false. Access checking is performed as if in
>   a context unrelated to T. Only the validity of the immediate context of the variable initialization is
>   considered.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/default_initializable) we find the following suggestion for a possible implementation:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept default_initializable =
    std::constructible_from<T> &&
    requires { T{}; } &&
    requires { ::new (static_cast<void*>(nullptr)) T; };
```

The placement-new operator invoked with a `nullptr` argument results in undefined behavior.

> [9)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) Called by the standard single-object placement new expression. The standard library implementation performs no action and returns ptr unmodified. The behavior is undefined if this function is called through a placement new expression and ptr is a null pointer.

My question is now: is the suggested possible implementation actually valid? On the one hand I think no, because an expression is involved which exhibits undefined behavior. On the other hand I think yes, because this expression occurs in unevaluated context and therefore may not need to have well-defined behavior (?) and just needs to be syntactically valid. But I cannot find clear evidence for one or the other.

Second question: if the latter turns out to be true, then why does this placement-new construction satisfy the standard's requirement that `T t;` must be well-formed? To me it looks like a strange hack, because neither simple nor compound requirements offer the possibility to require `T t;` exactly. But why does this work?

Comment: *"undefined if this function is called"* I think it's not UB, because it's not actually *called* in an unevaluated context.

Comment: I'm only going to comment since I don't have a standard quote, but I'm certain that UB requires that the offending code is actually executed. For example, given `int &foo` that is bound to an invalid target (say, a function local where the function has returned), the code `if (false) { std::cout << foo; }` is not UB because the target is never actually used. Put another way: there is no "behavior" if the code is not executed -- without behavior, there cannot be undefined behavior.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not sure that's the case. I can't think if an example of the top of my head, but I recall seeing an example of a program doing something weird, because of UB in a function that *was never even called*.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm going to agree with cigien on this one.  The mere existence of code with undefined behavior gives the compiler complete latitude to change the behavior of the rest of the code, even if the buggy code is never executed.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633 for interesting analysis.

Comment: @cigien When you say "never even called," do you mean a function that was defined but had no invocations in the entire program, or a function that _could_ be conditionally called based on the program's input but shouldn't've been?  There's a bit of a difference. If the function could be called, yes, I would agree that weird things could happen. If there isn't a single reference to the function in the entire program (no invocations, no taking a function pointer, etc.) then I'm not sure what context the UB would "infect."

Comment: @cdhowie Here's the [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyHyAIa5so&t=1380s) I was thinking of. There *isn't* any path that takes the address of a function, but the UB arises from the fact that the compiler assumes that there *must* be a path. I'm not sure if this actually answers your question about "never even called", but it's the example I was referring to.

Comment: @cigien Ok, but the compiler assumes that there must be a path because `main()` _already_ exhibits UB. It's the UB in `main()` that sends the compiler down the rabbit hole. That example doesn't really prove anything in the context of the discussion we are having. Now if that happened when `main()` _didn't_ invoke UB then I'd concede the point to you.

Comment: @cdhowie it is possible to cause UB in compiler, e.g. by pushing implementation's limits

Answer (score 2):

When specified, undefined behavior are the consequence of an evaluation [[expr.new]/20](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#20.sentence-3)

> If the allocation function is a non-allocating form ([new.delete.placement]) that returns null, the behavior is undefined.

[[expr.prim.req]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req):

> Expressions appearing within a requirement-body are unevaluated operands.

[[expr.prop]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#expr.context-1.sentence-2):

> An unevaluated operand is not evaluated.

So there are no undefined behavior has it requires a return value of the placement new allocation function, but such value is not computed.

If it were not the case such common construct `decltype( std::declval<int&>() + std::declval <int&> ())` would be UB too.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also elaborate on the second question, "why does this placement-new construction satisfy the standard's requirement that `T t;` must be well-formed"? Maybe there is a more general answer that does not nitpick on this example. Phrased differently I could ask: "why are constructs that would be UB in evaluated contextes valid requirements and how could we check that they really require what they should require?" For easy things like `decltype(...)` I can see it (because typing is independet from values in some sense). But is there a formal argument, why this is always correct?

Comment: @UniversE, I think, that trivially follows from point 2 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization): "Default initialization is performed in three situations... 2) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression with no initializer; ...", simply covering the dynamic storage duration case.

Comment: @Secundi ah I see. But then I believe this violates the standard. Because it says *if and only if* `T t;` is well-formed for some invented variable t. But the cppreference implementation brings placement-new into the game, which looks like it's violating the *only if* part of *if and only if*. But I must admit, I haven't checked the final phrasing in the standard, it was a draft back then and might have changed to include new-expression for default_initializable concept. I'll have a look later.

Comment: Yes, I also stumbled about that first. It boils down to the question: what are the exact strict constraints for this expression(!) to be well-formed? There should be a general part in the standard about that (automatic and dynamic storage duration?). Maybe it's also not that explicitly stated in the standard but for actual compilers relevant in order to have this expression well-formed for placement new/dynamic storage contexts as well.

Comment: Otherwise, the standard library would have to break a unique constraint further on possibly into non-symmetric counterparts suddenly, but surely, you don't want a `default_initializable<T>` that differs between the automatic storage duration and the dynamic storage duration case... :)

Comment: "But then I believe this violates the standard" No, since the the standard libraries implementation is only a possible realization, often related to own customized constraints. At the compiler level of perspective (i.e. expression level/language level), I'd agree with you although.