# What is an unevaluated operand in the way a 'requires expression' sees it?

Tags: c++, c++20

[Note 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#2) in the standard [[expr.prim.req.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general) states:

> Expressions appearing within a requirement-body are unevaluated operands.

Simply put, *unevaluated operands* are operands that is not evaluated.

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int fun(int) { return 5; }

template<typename R>
struct T { static R x; };

int main() {
  std::cout << fun(T<int>::x)  << std::endl;                    // Line A
  std::cout << requires { fun(T<int &&>::x); } << std::endl;    // Line B
  //std::cout << requires { fun(T<int &&&>::x); } << std::endl;   // Error: Line C
}
```

Its beyond doubt that Line A matches the expected types and compiles fine.

Line B, does not match the expected types (mismatched -l and -r values), but compiles fine anyway.

Along the same lines of reasoning, Line C, though containing an obvious error, *should* compile since the operands are not supposed to be evaluated. It goes without saying that I am intentionally trying to create a syntactically wrong statement here. Clang11 and gcc10.2 correctly identifies the reference-to-a-reference error. But the compiler is doing template deduction when, in my understanding, the statements should go unevaluated.

My question is: Why isn't `fun(T<int &&&>::x);` not going *unevaluated* in my code? Rather, it is being evaluated and template deduced.

The closest answers are: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798455/requires-ignores-a-field-is-not-static) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000436/is-ub-in-unevaluated-context-e-g-requires-expressions-still-ub) - but they are along the lines of 'undefined-behaviour'. I fail to interpret them in the context of my code. My current guess is that template deduction doesn't fall under the category of *unevaluated operands*.

Comment: That’s not what *evaluated* means: even doing overload resolution on the call isn’t evaluation.

Comment: Line B does not have a value category mismatch. `T<int&&>::x` is an lvalue (and even if it were an rvalue, it doesn't matter, since `fun` just takes an `int`?)

Comment: I thought int&& would be considered naively and therefore be considered as a rvalue reference (in how they are used typically in move constructors). I see now that 'x' is considered for type deduction (not int&&) and hence a lvalue. Anyway, it doesn't matter for `fun`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression still needs to be grammatically correct (as in, in compliance with C++'s grammar as outlined by the standard), evaluated or not. `int&&&` is not valid per the grammar. (there is no such thing as a *ref-qualifier* *ref-qualifier*)

(You can *kinda* get this by passing an lvalue to a template receiving `T&&`, but it will become `T&` via reference collapsing, but then it's clear that it's an rvalue reference to a reference and not the other way around --- `int&&&` is ambiguous and meaningless)

An unevaluated operand is *usually* an expression that is used to infer type information, and not for its side effects (whereas a *discarded value expression* is solely used for its side effects). Other examples of unevaluated operands:

```
T x;
auto typeInfo = typeid(x); // x is unevaluated
auto x_size = sizeof(x); // x is unevaluated
```

In the examples above it seems pretty obvious that nothing is really *done* with `x` since we're just naming a variable, but consider that the argument to `typeid` or `sizeof` can be *any* expression! The expression will not have any side effects because it is **unevaluated**; we only care about the resulting expression's *type* in those cases.

In the case of a *requires-expression*, the *requirement-body* (bit between the braces) requires an *expression*. Since `fun(T<int &&&>::x)` is grammatically incorrect, it's not an expression and hence a compiler error is emitted. (These expressions can be thought of as an easier & more powerful way to use SFINAE for enabling/disabling templates).

For all the compiler cares, you could have written `requires{abra;!?...-cadabra}` instead of `requires{fun(T<int &&&>::x);}` and they're equally invalid.

Comment: Awesome! The SFINAE mention makes absolute sense for a possible usage pattern of 'unevaluated' expressions.

Comment: The operand of `typeid` **is** evaluated if the expression has polymorphic class type!